# Fixing blurry text in older applications

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, resolution

On my Dell XPS 9570 (1920x1080), my text has been blurry, especially in older applications. I've fixed this before with this utility: http://windows10-dpi-fix.xpexplorer.com/

However, when connecting an external monitor (1920x1080), this fix results in text being magnified too high and there doesn't seem to be an option to change the custom scaling for only one monitor.

Are are there any alternative fixes I can try?

Comment: Have you adjusted Windows *Clear Type* settings?? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/cleartype/

Comment: Yes, I have adjusted a few times

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click your desktop > `Display Settings` or type `Display Settings` in the start menu.
2. This should open the *Display Settings* applet, showing all monitors present in the system. Scroll down until you see **Scale and layout**. If it's 125% or greater, old apps will show blurred content. Change it to 100%.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I'm aware this is the case. However, if I put the display on 100% on my laptop, the text becomes miniscule. Previously, the dpi fix let me run at 125% without issues, though due to the aforementioned issues, it's something I can no longer do.

Comment: @JeremyFeng Sorry to hear about that. Maybe you can get it working by acessing the link that's right below that setting, **Advanced scaling settings**? There's an option there to make the system try to fix it automatically. Changing it might make a difference, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Also go Windows Settings and search for Adjust ClearType text. Run this and set each Clear Type setting for best type.  Then search for Calibrate display and go through all the settings. Things like Gamma affect your display.

So do All suggested by both posts here.

Comment: Yup, I've done this.

Comment: It will be one of your applications doing this to your display. If you wish to consider a fix that may work and take some time, do a Windows 10 Repair Install and Keep Data only. This will make you reinstall your applications. Install one at a time until you find out which application is making the display blurry.